# How to add a database index to a base field

Tags: 8, entities, database

**Goal:**

Add a database index to a 'created' field.

**Given:**

There is a custom entity with a base field `created`.
The field is stored the entity table. 
Field source code of the `created` field:

```
$fields['created'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('created')
  ->setLabel(t('Created'))
  ->setDescription(t('The time that the entity was created.'))
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'label' => 'hidden',
    'type' => 'timestamp',
    'weight' => 3,
    'settings' => [
      'date_format' => 'medium',
      'custom_date_format' => '',
      'timezone' => '',
    ],
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

**What I researched:**

I have not found a way to add index using the `\Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition()`.

As I understand indexes are defined in a `@FieldType` plugin. The `created` field is implemented via the `\Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\TimestampItem()` plugin and obviously does not have have indexes there.

P.S. I know, that I can write an updatescript to add an index to the table manually.

Comment: Another option is to extend the TimestampItem class and use the setClass method to replace the default class.

Comment: @Eyal, yep, that is also an option. I can create a new `@FieldType` `created_indexed`.

Comment: Some plugins might check the field type I'd, so (if possible) it would be better to use the `created` field and only set the new class via the setClass method.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Currently the only way to do that is to create your own storage_schema entity handler.

See Node as an example, the annotation:

```
*     "storage_schema" = "Drupal\node\NodeStorageSchema",
```

There you can alter both the schema for a while table, or you can do it for a specific field. NodeStorageSchema does both:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function getEntitySchema(ContentEntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $reset = FALSE) {
    $schema = parent::getEntitySchema($entity_type, $reset);

    $schema['node_field_data']['indexes'] += array(
      'node__frontpage' => array('promote', 'status', 'sticky', 'created'),
      'node__status_type' => array('status', 'type', 'nid'),
      'node__title_type' => array('title', array('type', 4)),
    );

    return $schema;
  }
```

And below in getSharedTableFieldSchema():

```
if ($table_name == 'node_revision') {
  switch ($field_name) {
    case 'langcode':
      $this->addSharedTableFieldIndex($storage_definition, $schema, TRUE);
      break;

    case 'revision_uid':
      $this->addSharedTableFieldForeignKey($storage_definition, $schema, 'users', 'uid');
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Since drush entup is no more available, you have to use hook_update, take `node_update_8002()` as example. By the way `NodeStorageSchema::getEntitySchema` uses `if ($data_table = $this->storage->getDataTable()) {` which didn't work for me: `getDataTable`  returns `null`

Comment: If that's the only way to do it, then I gather Drupal has no support for using hook_entity_base_field_info() in one module to add a field to a custom entity created in another module, and then create a compound index on the table for that entity using the new field. So the only recourse would be to create the index directly with SQL from outside of Drupal, I suppose.

Answer (score 8):

For those wondering which part from berdir's reply is necessary for creating an index on a base column - here is a full example on creating index on a string column `sku`:

`ekr_product/Entity/Product.php:`

```
<?php

 * @ContentEntityType(
...
 *     "storage_schema" = "Drupal\ekr_product\ProductStorageSchema",
```

`ekr_product/ProductStorageSchema.php:`

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\ekr_product;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorageSchema;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionInterface;

/**
 * Defines the node schema handler.
 */
class ProductStorageSchema extends SqlContentEntityStorageSchema {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function getSharedTableFieldSchema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $storage_definition, $table_name, array $column_mapping) {
    $schema = parent::getSharedTableFieldSchema($storage_definition, $table_name, $column_mapping);
    $field_name = $storage_definition->getName();

    switch ($field_name) {
      case 'sku':
        $this->addSharedTableFieldIndex($storage_definition, $schema, TRUE);
        break;
    }

    return $schema;
  }

}
```

Few comments on this.

You might be thinking why using method `getSharedTableFieldSchema` when creating index on the **base** table? Truly, *shared* word is sorta associated with fields stored in a separate tables. But from the function's documentation it follows that if your schema modification isn't cross-field you should use exactly this function.

Note also that the third parameter to `addSharedTableFieldIndex` is set to `TRUE`. Suddenly this makes the column you're creating index on `NOT NULL`. This is the same as if you'd be doing:

```
$schema['fields']['your_field']['not null'] = TRUE;
```

somewhere in schema overrides. This is a way to make the column **required** at the database level.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for example! But additionally to those modifications, maybe we need to apply changes via hook_update function? Or they must be applied automatically on cache rebuild or other routine?

Answer (score 7):

Besides the options berdir posted, configurable fields can have manually added indexes via \Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig::$indexes

For example, in `field.storage.media.field_media_video_embed_field.yml` file you'd have:

```
indexes:
  field_media_video_embed_field__value:
    - value
```

to add an index on the `value` property. Note the second line in this example is just the index name and has no special meaning and could be anything else, it's just a naming convention. But the third line here needs to be the property name and *not* the SQL database column name (which would be `field_media_video_embed_field__value`).

Answer (score 2):

While the above API approaches are recommended, here's one more raw approach that can be useful for some cases.

In this case, it adds an SQL index to a base field for the MySQL/MariaDB database engine:

```
/**
 * Add SQL index on published_date base field
 */
function MY_MODULE_update_8010(&$sandbox) {
  // Add index
  // ALTER TABLE $table ADD INDEX $name ($column1, $column2..)
  db_query("ALTER TABLE node_field_data ADD INDEX node_field__published_date (published_date)");
}
```

Comment: I use this, too (in mymodule_install()) - because API is painful here. But add {} around the tablename incase you have a prefix set.

Comment: This is a bad idea because it just works when modifying existing sites - any new installs of my_module will not have the index defined. A proper solution needs to first change the entity definition so that the index is created AND define an update hook so that existing sites can have their schemas updated.

Comment: @anonymous for my case I usually need to add an index to an existing install, however it’s trivial to add the same code to a hook such as `hook_install` https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_install/9.4.x